# Why do I get an inconsistent result when I chain iterators instead of collecting to a temporary HashSet?

Tags: data-structures, rust, iterator, hashset

I'm writing a Rust function that takes a list of numbers and a maximum value, and sums all multiples of the given numbers up to the maximum (duplicates are counted once only).  The first version of the function I wrote was

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn sum_of_multiples(limit: u32, factors: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    let set: HashSet<u32> = factors
        .iter()
        .map(|factor| {
            let top: u32 = (limit - 1) / factor;

            (1..=top).map(move |num| num * factor)
        }).flatten()
        .collect();

    set.iter().fold(0, |acc, num| acc + num)
}
```

(I know merging `HashSets` like this probably isn't the best solution). This gives the expected result:

```
println!("{}", sum_of_multiples(100, &[3, 5])) // 2318
```

When I take out the call to `collect` in the middle and chain the last `fold`, I get a different answer:

```
pub fn sum_of_multiples(limit: u32, factors: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    let val: u32 = factors
        .iter()
        .map(|factor| {
            let top: u32 = (limit - 1) / factor;

            (1..=top).map(move |num| num * factor)
        }).flatten()
        .fold(0, |acc, num| acc + num);

    val
}
```

Result:

```
println!("{}", sum_of_multiples(100, &[3, 5])) // 2633
```

I know the iterators are evaluated lazily, but I assumed they are evaluated in sequence in the order that they are used.  Is this because of the behavior of `flatten` with `HashSet`s?  I don't understand why the results are different the second time round, or what the significance (if any) of 2633 is.

Comment: "function that takes a list of numbers and a maximum value, and sums all multiples of the given numbers up to the maximum (duplicates are counted once only)." please for this kind of thing do a exemple of input and output that cover all your need, because my head is already burning to trying to match what you said with your personal way of coding.

Comment: Extra pro-tips: (1) provide a link to the Playground (like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8944be7f2b868489c25f12d09452df6d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)) whenever possible; (2) `flatten` after `map` can be obtained with just a single `flat_map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have removed the intermediate `HashSet`, which was actually serving a purpose, according to your original statement of requirements:

> duplicates are counted once only

Removing the step of storing the values in a `HashSet` means that duplicates will be counted each time they occur, which should explain the difference.

Comment: Ah yeah, so they join up consecutively.  I had it in my head rust still knew it was a set.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You didn't remove duplicates in your second snippet because you consume your iterator directly.

> (I know merging `HashSet`s like this probably isn't the best solution).

As you need temporary storage to remove duplicates, maybe you could use a `Vec` and then put it in a set, or instead of using a set, you could sort the `Vec` and filter duplicate values yourself, but this needs testing.

> Also, `itertools` provides a [unique](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique) adaptor, which keeps track of unique values internally. – [E_net4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4)

This one should be tested too. This allows you to not worry about how it is implemented.

Finally, you can write your function in one expression:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn sum_of_multiples(limit: u32, factors: &[u32]) -> u32 {
    factors
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|factor| {
            let top = (limit - 1) / factor;

            (1..=top).map(move |num| num * factor)
        })
        .collect::<HashSet<u32>>()
        .iter()
        .sum()
}
```

Comment: Also, `itertools` provides a [`unique`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.unique) adaptor, which keeps track of unique values internally.

Comment: @E_net4: That being said, complexity wise, there's bond to be a `HashSet` or `BTreeSet` in there anyway; `itertools` just makes writing it easier.